# Looking for breakdown for a python replace substring script

Tags: python-3.x, string, windows

I'm learning this script of how to replace substrings in a string and i stumbled on the while loop and i didn't understand the use and logic behind using the before and after variables and generally how the while loop panned out. I checked online and i noticed they use the replace method but i want to understand this conventional step and logic.

```
things = "tree, box, chair, lamp, \n" \
    "desk, cat, dog, grass, \n" \
    "pig, box, lamp, shelf"
print(things)
print()

old_item = input("Old item: ")
new_item = input("New item: ")
len_old_item = len(old_item) # i didn't get why they added this.

i = things.find(old_item) 
while i > 0:
    before = things[:i] # i don't get how this part works
    after = things[i+len_old_item:] # i don't get how this part works
    things = before + new_item +after # i don't get how this part works
    i = things.find(old_item) # i don't get how this part works

print()
print(things)
```

The output asks the user to enter an old item from the list and then replaces it in the list of things with the new item.

Comment: Add some `print` statements to see those values in the loop.

Comment: Okay. I'll try that asap. Thanks AAA